# windows SNMP extension agent trap SetEvent ( ) calling sequence

Tags: windows, snmp

What is the calling sequence into **SetEvent()** in a Windows SNMP extension agent? I need to signal a trap in my extension agent.

How/where do the arguments to SetEvent( ) appear when SnmpExtensionTrap( ) receives control?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question: there are no arguments to SetEvent( ). Just SetEvent( hTrap ) and get control at SnmpExtensionTrap( ) with the documented args:

```
SnmpExtensionTrap(
  OUT AsnObjectIdentifier *enterprise,
  OUT AsnInteger          *genericTrap,
  OUT AsnInteger          *specificTrap,
  OUT AsnTimeticks        *timeStamp,
  OUT SnmpVarBindList     *variableBindings) {
```

Now it's up to you to find out why your agent code requested the trap. Fill in the pointers in the arg list and return TRUE (you have another trap to send after this one) or FALSE (no more traps to send).